# Use text file to provide input for etree xml

Tags: python-2.7, elementtree

I have a xml file and I need to change 2 parameters in this xml file from the etee.

```
XML file:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ABC_Input xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >
<REQ>  
<!-- Optional in XSD -->
<INFO>ALL</INFO>
</REQ>
<PO>
<PO_ID>3557698</PO_ID>
<!-- Req in XSD -->
<RAN>HQF011512C</RAN>
<!-- Req in XSD -->
</PO>
</ABC_Input>
```

I have written below code to achieve this

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('alpha.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for val in root.findall('PO')
   val.find('RAN').text="HQ123"
tree.write('output1.xml')
```

Now I need to pass value of RAN & PO_ID from text file as input  then how is that possible?

Comment: how does this text file looks like?

Comment: taxt file contains 2 entries in 2 line: RAN:HQF011512
PO_ID:3557698

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

# Read the file (called alpha.txt) and extract the lines
lines = []
with open('alpha.txt', 'r') as txtF:
    lines = txtF.readlines()

# A dictionary to hold PO_ID and RAN values 
values = {}
# If there are multiple values of PO_ID or RAN then it will take the last entry in the text file
for line in lines:
    line = line.strip()
    if 'RAN' in line:
        values['RAN'] = line[line.find('RAN')+len('RAN')+1:]
    elif 'PO_ID' in line:
        values['PO_ID'] = line[line.find('PO_ID')+len('PO_ID')+1:]
    else:
        continue

tree = ET.parse('alpha.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for val in root.findall('PO'):
    val.find('PO_ID').text = values['RAN']
    val.find('RAN').text = values['PO_ID']
tree.write('output1.xml')
```

Comment: In text file alpha.txt if I provide input as 

    alpha.xml
    RAN:HQF011512 
    PO_ID:3557698 

    gamma.xml
    RAM:454567
    CASE:AASDFE 

and in my code instead of writing alpha.xml, whichever xml name is present in nnotepad,  it will update tag value in  that xml with the provided tag in notepad
tree = ET.parse('alpha.xml')

ex: now code will update RAN & PO_ID in alpha.xml and RAM & CASE in gamma.xml

Comment: yes you can easily do that. Just change the parsing loop `for line in lines` and the dictionary structure to include all the values you need from the text file. Something like: `{'alpha.xml':{'PO_ID':3557698, 'RAN':HQF011512}, 'gamma.xml':{'RAM':123, 'CASE':456}}`

Comment: thanks but what I have to parse in code or can you show me where can I update in dictionary and in loop

    tree = ET.parse('alpha.xml')

Comment: Just try it out, if u r stuck post the error msg and your trial code. Basically you know how to read a txt file and how to parse a xml file therefore should not be a big problem.